# Error usando Ajax Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Quiero pasar unos datos por POST usando AJAX para insertar en base de datos estoy trabajando en laravel 5.1.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Hay un limite de parametros que se pueden enviar por Ajax? Porque tengo varios y si quito uno no pasa nada, inserta pero si lo coloco da error de javascript.

**Código:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'/estimates',
    dataType:'json',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    //  data:{DatosEstimado:DatosEstimado,Estimado:Estimado,descuento:descuento,gananciatotal},
    data: 
         {
           company_id:company_id,prove_id:prove_id,estado:estado,
           fecha_soli:fecha_soli,resumen:resumen,metodo:metodo,
           proximo_seguimiento:proximo_seguimiento,
           fbo:fbo,cantidad_fuel:cantidad_fuel,localidad:localidad,
           avion_id:avion_id,tipoCama:tipoCama,
           Estimado:Estimado, descuento:descuento,
           totalDescuento:totalDescuento,
           gananciatotal:gananciatotal,
           total:total,subtotal:subtotal,tipoCategoria:tipoCategoria
          },
    success: function (estimado) {
      $('#mensaje').toggleClass('alert alert alert-success');
      $('#mensaje').html(estimado);
      console.log(estimado);
      //  window.location()
      //   location.href ="/estimates/index";
      //Recargar el plugin para que tenga la funcionalidad del componente$("#idMunicipio").select({ placeholder: "Selecciona un Municipio", width: "20%" });
        },
        //Mensaje de error en caso de fallo
        error: function (ex) {
          $('#mensaje').toggleClass('alert alert alert-danger');
          $('#mensaje').html('Ocurrio un error inesperado: '+ex);
            alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
        }
  });
```

Comment: Seria buno que colocaras el error que te da el javascript

Comment: @BenjaminDelaCruz El error está en el título y se debe a un desborde en la pila de llamadas. Generalmente ocurre cuando se llama recursivamente a una función compleja sin parar, ocasionando el desborde.

Comment: He visto este error antes y, casi siempre se debe a que **algunos valores no son válidos**.  Te recomiendo que verifiques que todos esos valores que envías sean válidos. Por ejemplo, si uno de esos campos es un elemento DOM, [obtendrás un Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://jsfiddle.net/drqpvdxu/).

Comment: Tal como te comentan, el error puede deberse a que enviar datos invalidos o bien, que alguna funcion se este ejecutando N veces. Utiliza el depurador de consola, pon puntos de interrupcion hy verifica el valor de  `data`

Answer (score 2):

El error puede deberse a varios intentos de Ajax de serializar tu JSON. Entonces, mejor lo serializamos antes de enviarlo usando [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify):

```
//Pongo el arreglo en una variable, sólo para que el código quede más amigable
        var miData = {
           company_id:company_id,prove_id:prove_id,estado:estado,
           fecha_soli:fecha_soli,resumen:resumen,metodo:metodo,
           proximo_seguimiento:proximo_seguimiento,
           fbo:fbo,cantidad_fuel:cantidad_fuel,localidad:localidad,
           avion_id:avion_id,tipoCama:tipoCama,
           Estimado:Estimado, descuento:descuento,
           totalDescuento:totalDescuento,
           gananciatotal:gananciatotal,
           total:total,subtotal:subtotal,tipoCategoria:tipoCategoria
          };


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'/estimates',
    dataType:'json',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    //  data:{DatosEstimado:DatosEstimado,Estimado:Estimado,descuento:descuento,gananciatotal},
    data: JSON.stringify(miData),
    success: function (estimado) {
      $('#mensaje').toggleClass('alert alert alert-success');
      $('#mensaje').html(estimado);
      console.log(estimado);
      //  window.location()
      //   location.href ="/estimates/index";
      //Recargar el plugin para que tenga la funcionalidad del componente$("#idMunicipio").select({ placeholder: "Selecciona un Municipio", width: "20%" });
        },
        //Mensaje de error en caso de fallo
        error: function (ex) {
          $('#mensaje').toggleClass('alert alert alert-danger');
          $('#mensaje').html('Ocurrio un error inesperado: '+ex);
            alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
        }
  });
```